# Showing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{1}{( 1+x^{2})^n}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Define:

$$ I(n) = \sqrt{n}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty} \frac{1}{( 1+x^{2})^n} \, dx$$

I have to show that:

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n} I(n) = \sqrt{\pi} $$

**Classical solution:**

Based on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1324342/587007)  we have a closed form for the integral:

$$ I(n) = \sqrt{\pi}\,\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n)}$$

Also from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2556322/587007) we get:

$$\sqrt{n}\,\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n)} \to 1 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty $$
Any other methods?

Comment: @SangchulLee That would make a good answer.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, Thank you, I migrated my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Migrated from comment)* Using the substitution $\sqrt{n}x=u$, we get

$$ \sqrt{n} I(n) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(1 + \frac{u^2}{n}\right)^{-n} \, \mathrm{d}u.$$

Since $(1 + u^2/n)^n \geq 1 + u^2$, the above integrands are dominated by the integrable function $1/(1+u^2)$, and so, by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n} I(n) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac{u^2}{n}\right)^{-n} \, \mathrm{d}u = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u = \sqrt{\pi}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $I_n=2\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}}$

> Use substitution $t=\tan u$ and obtain: $$\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^n}}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{({\cos{u})^{2n-2}}du}=W_{2n-2}\sim\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n-1}}$$ see [Wallis’s Integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals).
>   Thus: $$\sqrt{n}I(n)\sim\sqrt{\pi\frac{n}{n-1}}$$

Comment: thanks very much and +1